# File functionalities from Java 8 on Java 7 in Android project

Tags: java, android, file, java-8, java-7

As i am doing a backporting task i need to get an application from Android 9 to Android 5.1 to work.
It contains a lot of functionalities related to files like Exporting and importing of Json files and creating directories.
Is there an alternative to the File functionalities found in Java 8, or a way to get them in Java 7 or some library that backports those as i just cannot find a solution to this.

Thanks!

Here are is a method as an example of what i would like to backport.

```
public static void exportLogcats(final Context context, final List<BootEvent> events,
                                 final String outputFolder) throws IOException {
    if (events == null) {
        return;
    }

    final String sourceFolder =
        new File(context.getFilesDir(), LOGCAT_FOLDER).getAbsolutePath();
        final Path outputPath;
        outputPath = Paths.get(outputFolder);
        deleteDirectory(outputPath);
        Files.createDirectories(outputPath);

    for (BootEvent event : events) {
        final String filename = event.getLogcatFilename();
        try {
                final Path source;
                source = Paths.get(sourceFolder, filename);
                final Path destination = Paths.get(outputFolder, filename);
                Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not copy file " + filename, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that calls like
.get on Paths, .createDirectories or .copy on Files does not work on API level 22

Comment: "Is there an alternative to the File functionalities found in Java 8" -- you may want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] of what you are using from Java 8, and perhaps people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing enough information.
I thought it was enough to get an understanding.
I have updated the text with a snippet and few specific methods for a better understanding of the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are countless examples of recursive-deletion and file-copying algorithms for Java. You can find them using any major search engine. `createDirectories()` should be equivalent to `mkdirs()` on `File`.

Comment: [AndroidRetroFile](https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidRetroFile) looks interesting. Haven't used it myself though.

Comment: AndroidRetroFile seemed like the perfect solution, and just after implementing it, i was told it is not actually functional as there is no FileSystemProvider and requires a lot of adjusting and bugfixing to use it. It seems more like an interface sadly.

Comment: @Chakson Oh, I understand, that's useful to know. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: For everyone facing the same problem, i have found a solution atleast for the file manipulation part. (not a solution for things like Paths.get() ).

https://github.com/sromku/android-storage

Can confirm this library works fine.